# Coupled Oscillators with unknown spring constants

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coupled-oscillators

For a problem, I had the following coupled oscillator system
[image: System in question]

for objects A, B and C of mass 0.13 kg and I am given two of the three proper vectors given as
$$\left|1\right\rangle =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & -3\end{array}\right),\left|2\right\rangle =\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
27 & -10 & 9\end{array}\right)$$ and I am told that the lowest mode frequency is $\omega=20 \text{ rad/s}$. With all this information I am asked to determine the spring constants $k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$ and $k_4$.

I solved the problem, by showing the lowest frequency is associated to the first mode $\left|1\right\rangle$ and I found 
$$k_2=52-k_1$$
$$k_3=\frac{52-k_1}{3}$$
$$k_4=\frac{104+k_1}{3}.$$

I know no one wants to try it out to see if I'm right but you don't need to, my question is "is it normal to have a free variable or was I supposed to find actual numerical values?"

If I was supposed to find numerical values, what other equation did I miss out?